# SPYDER and IPython 4.0 support

Tags: python, ipython, spyder, jupyter

I recently installed `ipython 4.0` to use `JUPYTER NOTEBOOK`. I used `SPYDER` as IDE for development in `Python`, but now `SPYDER` doesn't work.

Why `spyder` does not support `ipython 4.0`?

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2696

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running on a linux environment, try to start spyder from the command line, once you have the PATH pointing to the anaconda 'bin' folder. The spyder executable there should be upgraded.